# Reference citations sequence for "Crescent Classification"

Tags: citations, peer-review

Kindly can one guide me about crescent classification in references citation. 
I have received a review that is following

> "for instance in the sequence of citations [5], [7] and [6], which must
>   be changed to cope to a crescent classification"

I have searched through the google but couldn't find any solution or knowledge about it.

Thanks.

Comment: I assume it couldn't be a technical term from your field (e.g., crescent fractures)?  I don't think "crescent classification" means anything in reference citations.  What's the broader context surrounding this sentence in the review?  My best guess is that the reviewer might be complaining that 5,7,6 are not in order (one of the more obscure meanings of "crescent" is "increasing", and the quote refers to the "sequence of citations"), but this would be exceptionally poor communication.  I really can't think of any clear meaning.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is not anything technical "crescent classification" related to my paper. I have rechecked my paper but couldnt find 5,7,6 (not in order sequence).

Comment: The order of using citations in your article should be: "Sentence A [5], Sentence B [6] also explained in [7]". Make sure that the order your citations appear in your text are [1], [2], [3], [4]....

Comment: Is it possible that the referee isn't complaining about occurrences in the text but rather the ordering of the bibliography at the end of the paper? (And I assume "cope" is a typo that should be "come".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, numerical citations are required to be sorted in increasing order. It might not be a hard requirement for all the journals which use numerical citations, but it makes citations more readable, and it allows abbreviations such as "[5-7]", instead of "[5], [6] and [7]".

The example given by the reviewer can essentially arise in two cases:

1. **The reference list is not sorted according to the citation order:** The solution here is, indeed, to sort the list of references according to the citation order. The way to achieve this depends on the typesetting system you are using. If you had typeset the manuscript with LaTeX and set-up the references with Bib(La)TeX, let them fix the order by using suitable options (for more detail on this, search the documentation; if this fails, ask on [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)). If you had set-up the list of references manually (I hope not), then manually change the order.
2. **There are multiple citations along the manuscript with inconsistent order:** Suppose that in Section I you have cited three references with order [1], [2], and [3], and then in Section II you have cited those references again, in the same sentence, but with different order, e.g., [3], [1], and [2]. Here the solution is to rephrase the sentence in Section II to cite the references in the order [1], [2], and [3].

This is as far I can go with the details you provided.

Comment: Does this mean that references appear several times in the reference list if they are cited multiple times in the paper? I am generally curious about the advantages of this sorting of the references (I have never seen any math paper that does this, and I would find it very odd).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft No, references appear just once, but if you use LaTeX the order in the list is decided by the first citation.

Comment: This just makes it sound like a rather random thing to sort by. I can see a very slight advantage in being able to cite as you mention here, but it also seems like often enough, this will not be possible anyway, if the references have appeared previously. And it certainly makes it an annoying task to check if a given paper has been cited.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I think that the main advantage is that of saving space: compare [1-5] with Author A (1999), Author B (2002) etc. Many engineering conferences or journals have limits on the number of pages. For instance, a major confetence in my field has a 2-page limit for the summaries and a 4-page limit for the extended papers: in those cases you want your refetences to be as short as possible.

Comment: But [1-5] is not that much shorter than [1,2,3,4,5] or [1],[2],[3],[4],[5]. Are length restrictions really severe enough that saving a few dozen characters is worth it?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes, you wouldn't believe at what authors sometimes to do save space. For instance, in conference papers, I frequently define symbols only in figure captions, because there the font is smaller and allows me to write a bit more ;-)

Comment: References sorted according to citation order, while almost never seen in mathematics, are common in some other fields.

Answer (score 1):

The term "crecent classification" could very well be a bad translation from Spanish "clasificación creciente" (roughly, "increasing order"). Perhaps the reviewer isn't a native English speaker (writer?).

In any case, it is customary (in numerical citation, like what LaTeX' BibTeX gives with its `plain` (default) format is to just cite them like e.g. `[1, 3, 5-7]` in increasing order (the `\cite{...}` command does so automatically if given several citations in one go, governed by options).